# less-middleware does't work - "Express 500 Error: Unrecognised input"

Tags: node.js, express, less

I'm using Express framework with less-middleware and jade template engine

When I'm trying to get my css file in browser "/css/style.css" - I get the error
"Express 500 Error: Unrecognised input"

Here is basic setup in app.js

```
var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('view options', {
    layout: false
});
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(app.router);


// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get("/api/places", api.getAllPlaces);
app.get("/api/place/:id", api.getOnePlace);

app.all('*', routes.index);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your filesystem layout under the `public` directory and the content of `public/css/styl.less`?

Comment: I think i've resolved this issue just after asking it. It was simply typo in less file. Thanks

Comment: OK, please answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: FYI `if ('development' == app.get('env'))` is synonymous with `app.configure('development', function() { ... })`. Also, it's generally considered better, performance wise, to configure the express router *before* the `static` file server (at least if you don't provide a named route for it). Finally, you shouldn't need to call `app.use(app.router)` explicitly, it is implicitly added when you register your first route (in your case `app.get("/api/places", api.getAllPlaces);`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was just typo in *.less file. Thanks!